# Difference between Ethernet and USART?

Tags: serial, ethernet, protocol, usart

As i made literal study about protocols, I came across lot of protocols and there differences but i'm not sure of what is the major merits of Ethernet over USART. lots of websites explained about all the serial protocols such as I2C, UART, USART, SPI, CAN, RS-232 and there's merits and demerits. but none of them between Ethernet over USART.

please tel me major features of Ethernet over USART.

Comment: You probably didn't find such information because they are so different that there is no sensible way to compare them. It would be like comparing a water biscuit (a cracker) to a wedding cake. Ethernet is the wedding cake.

Comment: @Martin Here is the requirement that some data resided in the Micro-Controller(STM32) are read by the computer systems. In order to do so I required to interface it, so how i could do that via Ethernet or USART.

Comment: My comment got too long so I changed it to a post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USART is a lot simpler. Its a point to point connection where the data sent by one thing gets received by the other thing. The data just shows up when the serial port is read.  You need a transceiver chip like a MAX232 to convert levels properly if going to a standard serial port on a computer. There are cables / adapters available to connect to "ttl" levels directly to a microcontroller. They must both be the correct voltage for the STM32 (3.3 or 5 volts). For ethernet you need hardware for the interface, plus a "protocol stack" which is a bunch of code that handles ip address and the tcp/ip protocol. Usually to interface via ethernet, there will be a whole interface chip or an entire sheild like in the Arduino world. Ethernet devices can talk to any other device on the network. (Or the world, if connected to the internet)